# PrimeNG p-calendar not working with Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, primeng

This issue has no errors in developer console or on the Spring Backend.  The date field is blank when trying to edit an existing record using a Reactive Form and `patchValue`.

Date Input Code:

```
<div class="p-field p-col">
    <label for="dueDate">Due Date</label>
    <p-calendar formControlName="dueDate" id="dueDate" showButtonBar="true" [showIcon]="true" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

Edit Function:

```
edit(id) {
    this._tasksService.getDetails(id).subscribe( x => {
        this.id = id;
        this.taskForm.patchValue(x);
        this.taskDialog = true;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that the p-calendar requires a JS Date.  Relying only on `patchValue` is not enough.

To correct this problem change the edit function to add the JS Date type.

```
edit(id) {
    this._tasksService.getDetails(id).subscribe( x => {
        this.id = id;
        x.dueDate = new Date(x.dueDate); 
        this.taskForm.patchValue(x);
        this.taskDialog = true;
    })
}
```